# In C# (or .NET in general) can you mask the call stack level where an exception was thrown via attributes?

Tags: c#, vb6, exception, callstack

The title may be a little confusing so I'll explain.  Say you had this call chain...

```
public DoWork(index) >> private DoWorkHelper(index) >> private CheckIndex(index)
```

Now if you call `DoWork`, it traverses the calls down to `CheckIndex`, adding each deeper call to the call stack.

Now if someone calls `DoWork` with a bad value for `index`, it throws the exception all the way down at `CheckIndex`, and currently, that's where the debugger breaks.  You then have to walk back up the call stack to see the real offender was that someone passed bad data to `DoWork`.

Now back in the VB6 days, you could simply decorate `DoWorkHelper` and `CheckIndex` with an attribute to say 'If any exception is thrown inside me, don't highlight me, but rather my caller because they were the ones that passed me bad crap!'  So in this case, the code would break inside `DoWork` with the call to `DoWorkHeper` highlighted.

There was also a setting to disable this so for deeper debugging purposes it could still be thrown at `CheckIndex`,  the level where it actually occurred, but half the time, breaking down there tells you nothing because you don't know how you got there without walking back up the call stack.

Think of it a way to decorate your code to say when you hit an exception, auto-traverse the call stack to the point where the bad value actually tells you something useful.

Note this is similar to 'Break On All Exceptions' except you're handling this via decoration.  Plus, you're not setting to break on a specific type of exception (e.g. all null reference exceptions, etc.) but rather a specific method! (or more accurately, the one that called the decorated method.)

So does C# or .NET in general have this?

---

### Update

While I credit Dark Falcon for the answer since he directed me there, I've added a more detailed explanation about what all the attributes mean, and in what context.  Check it out below.

Comment: Does the [DebuggerStepThrough()] attribute help?

Comment: @Kane, sort of!  It looks like this and the ones @Dark talked about are all related.  But you didn't put this as an answer so I can't mark yours! :)  Still, I voted yours up.

Comment: Note that VB6 never had such an attribute. what it DID have was a global (to all projects) "break in class module" setting.

Comment: Actually @Deanna, you're incorrect.  There was an attribute that you could place on a code block that works exactly like I described.  This is separate from what you are referring to.  It wasn't that well-known, but for those of us who did know about it, it really helped debugging.  As soon as I find my old VB6 code (it's been years!) I'll update the answer with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the [Just My Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx) option. You need to decorate `DoWorkHelper` with `DebuggerHiddenAttribute` or `DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute`.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding what I've found to better explain so people don't have to go looking elsewhere...

There are three attributes related to this: `DebuggerHidden`, `DebuggerStepThrough`, and `DebuggerNonUserCode`.

Here are the rules:

When `Just My Code` is ***not*** checked:

- `DebuggerNonUserCode`
  This is basically ignored.  Breakpoints, step-into and exceptions all work the same as if this attribute wasn't there.
- `DebuggerStepThrough`
  This respects breakpoints and will break on exceptions where they occur, but you cannot manually step into blocks marked with this attribute.
- `DebuggerHidden`
  This doesn't allow you to step in to these blocks, it ignores breakpoints, and any exceptions thrown are handled in the calling method, not where they actually occur.

When `Just My Code` ***is*** checked

- All three attributes behave the same as if you had used `DebuggerHidden` above.

There's another attribute, `DebuggerStepperBoundary` that is pretty cool.  Here's the excerpt from MSDN:

> Use the DebuggerStepperBoundaryAttribute to escape from stepping through code to running code. For example, in Visual Studio 2005, encountering a DebuggerStepperBoundaryAttribute while stepping through code using the F10 key (or Step Over command) has the same effect as pressing the F5 key or using the Start Debugging command.

Hope this clears things up!  Sure did for me!

Comment: I believe DebuggerHidden also removes the call form the stack trace.

Comment: That would make sense since the exception is now thrown at the calling location, meaning it's technically already back from that call, hence it's popped off of the stack.