# Can you decorate a debug-breaking function to instead break where that function is called from?

Tags: swift, debugging, swift4, callstack

This is best explained with an example.  Consider this `mustOverride` helper function:

```
func mustOverride(callSite:String = #function) -> Never {
    preconditionFailure("\(callSite) must be overridden in a subclass")
}
```

We use it to make faux abstract classes, like so:

```
// Faux 'abstract' class
class SoundBase {

    func play(){
        mustOverride()
    }
}

// 'Concrete' class
class CatSound : SoundBase {

    override func play(){
        // play cat 'meow' sound
    }
}
```

With the above, if you instantiate a `SoundBase` directly and call `play()`, you'll trigger the `mustOverride()` function which breaks in a debuggable state. The issue is it breaks inside the `mustOverride()` function, not at the call site `play()`.

Microsoft's .NET has a neat feature where you can decorate functions with attributes to change how they interact with the debugger ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623856/168179) for more info).

For instance, they have a `DebuggerHidden` attribute that, if applied to `mustOverride()`, would cause the debugger to instead break inside the calling `play()` function and *not* inside `mustOverride()` which saves you an unnecessary trip to the call stack just to back up one level to find out where the error really is.

I'm wondering if Swift has anything similar to this capability. It's really great when used appropriately.

Comment: I assume throwing an error in mustOverride() and catching it in play() does not apply to your case?

Comment: No, it's not about the error or catching it at runtime. It's about the call stack when debugging and wanting to always ignore the last frame and go to the one before.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're debugging in Xcode, what you are looking for is the [`@_transparent`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/TransparentAttr.rst) attribute. Here it is in action:

```
@_transparent
func mustOverride(callSite: String = #function) -> Never {
    preconditionFailure("\(callSite) must be overridden in a subclass")
}

class SoundBase {
    func play(){
        mustOverride()
    }
}

class CatSound: SoundBase {
    override func play() {}
}

SoundBase().play()
```

And the result: [image]

From the documentation:

> Semantically, `@_transparent` means something like "treat this operation as if it were a primitive operation". The name is meant to imply that both the compiler and the compiled program will "see through" the operation to its implementation.

Note:

- Since `@_transparent` starts with an underscore, it may change in the future

Comment: Interesting.  There are apparently a *lot* of other rules here (from the docs) that may make this unusable in some cases, but I think this is the closest that I'm going to get to what I'm after.  I'll leave this open a little longer to see if anyone comes up with something better/closer, but if not, I'll mark this as the answer.  Thanks!